# bash awk first 1st column and 3rd column with everything after

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

I am working on the following bash script:

```
# contents of dbfake file
1 100% file 1
2 99%  file name 2
3 100% file name 3

#!/bin/bash

# cat out data
cat dbfake |

# select lines containing 100%
grep 100% |

# print the first and third columns
awk '{print $1, $3}' |

# echo out id and file name and log
xargs -rI % sh -c '{ echo %; echo "%" >> "fake.log"; }'

exit 0
```

This script works ok, but how do I print everything in column $3 and then all columns after?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use cut instead of awk in this case:

```
  cut -f1,3- -d ' '
```

Answer (score 9):

```
awk '{ $2 = ""; print }' # remove col 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a little whitespace:

```
awk '{ $2="" }1'
```

But [UUOC](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/UUOC) and `grep`:

```
< dbfake awk '/100%/ { $2="" }1' | ...
```

If you'd like to trim that whitespace:

```
< dbfake awk '/100%/ { $2=""; sub(FS "+", FS) }1' | ...
```

---

---

For fun, here's another way using `GNU sed`:

```
< dbfake sed -r '/100%/s/^(\S+)\s+\S+(.*)/\1\2/' | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Others responded in various ways, but I want to point that using xargs to multiplex output is rather bad idea.

Instead, why don't you:

```
awk '$2=="100%" { sub("100%[[:space:]]*",""); print; print >>"fake.log"}' dbfake
```

That's all. You don't need grep, you don't need multiple pipes, and definitely you don't need to fork shell for every line you're outputting.

You could do `awk ...; print}' | tee fake.log`, but there is not much point in forking tee, if awk can handle it as well.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
awk 'sub(/.*100% /,"")' dbfake | tee "fake.log"
```